# Is there a way to stop the "Source" block from generating agents after a specific time in AnyLogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent

Utilizing a `source` generating agents on an Interarrival time basis, I would like to stop the `source` block from generating agents after a certain amount of time passing so that the model can continue to process the agents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to encapsulate all the logic inside the source block, without external events or variables, would be to select `Multiple agents per arrival` as true and then have a conditional statement for the number of agents, for example `time() > 10 ? 0 : 1`, so that after 10 model time units there will no agents arriving

[image]

Comment: How would this snippet look if I would like a uniform distribution of 3,5?

Comment: `time() > 10 ? 0 : uniform(3,5)` . See the help to learn how to code distributions. Or use the distribution wizard (again check the help on that)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, you have helped me solve my problem. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I receive a type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int

Comment: Number of agents must be an int. So use uniform_disc()

Answer (score 1):

Sure. If it is a inter-arrival source block, make it use a variable as the interrarrival time, of type double:
[image]

Then, create an event that triggers once only, after your specific time. Make it change the variable to 0 as below. Make SURE to trigger it not at time 0 (as in the screen but when you need it!):

NOTE: Do not set `myRate = 0;. Instead, set it to` infinity` to actually have no more arrivals.
[image]

Comment: Maybe I should have specified, it is an Interarrival time!

Comment: yes. Please edit the question, I will edit the reply :)

Comment: And please always be specific with questions :) See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow for more tips :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Benjamin! Will do.

Comment: I encounter the problem that once the desired time is reached, my source outputs thousands of agents and the entire model stops on a model logic error.

Comment: new problem, new question :) (SOF does not work like a forum with back'n'forth comms)

Comment: This is because the proposed solution sets the inter-arrival time to 0, so there is no time in between arrivals… to stop the arrivals it should have been set to Double.Infinity. @Benjamin just update your answer.

Comment: ha, good point, thx @Jaco-BenVosloo

Comment: Thanks gents. Jaco's original answer seems to do the trick.